# get command prompt result when remotely call a .cmd file

Tags: cmd.exe

I am trying to call cmd files from a lot of servers. so the cmds will be executed  then I　will receive the results.

but if we run the cmd manually on any of the server, them it will pop up the cmd prompt then showing the process till its done(endlocal)

is it possible to actually pop that CMD　command result to a log file alone with the output. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this at the commandline: "name of the command" > cmd.log. This will push the output of the command to the cmd.log file.

Edit:

I think you may want to use PsExec (technet.microsoft.com/pl-PL/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Using this you can invoke remote commands. I think you can keep the command files locally and can make them execute on the remote server.

Comment: but I need the cmd logs executed on the remote server

Comment: I think you may want to use PsExec (http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-PL/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Using this you can invoke remote commands. I think you can keep the command files locally and can make them execute on the remote server.